# Android 2.3 Keyboard stops popping after after watching video in WebView

Tags: android, input, webview, video-streaming

I have a simple application with a `WebView` which loads an html page.
The HTML page contains only an `input` field and an `iframe` in it, the `iframe` is used to embed a youtube video.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Video Test</legend>
            <input type="text" id="text-callee-dataReceived" name="text-callee-dataReceived" size="80" value="" />
            <iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/-qTIGg3I5y8" frameborder="0">
    </iframe>
</fieldset>
```

When I tap on the input field the keyboard comes up as expected. However when I play the video first and then tap on the input field the keyboard does not come up even though the input field gets focus (i.e. the cursor show up in it and blinks).

Note: I have not been able to reproduce this when I visit the HTML page using the Android browser.

Anyone have any idea whats going on or if I can fix this some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the cause is the bug that is described here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7189

So try to set focus programmatically:

```
webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                    v.requestFocus();
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today. The following solution worked for me:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.requestFocus();
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: @Adi Inbar Thank you for your modification!